# Check if Pokemon can evolve

Tags: c#

I have Pokemon.cs here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PokemonPocket{
    public class PokemonMaster{
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public int NoToEvolve {get; set;}
        public  string EvolveTo {get; set;}

        public PokemonMaster(string name, int noToEvolve, string evolveTo){
            this.Name = name;
            this.NoToEvolve = noToEvolve;
            this.EvolveTo = evolveTo;
        }
    }
```

and this is the code I have been working on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PokemonPocket
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //PokemonMaster list for checking pokemon evolution availability.    
            List<PokemonMaster> pokemonMasters = new List<PokemonMaster>(){
            new PokemonMaster("Pikachu", 2, "Raichu"),
            new PokemonMaster("Eevee", 3, "Flareon"),
            new PokemonMaster("Charmander", 1, "Charmeleon")
            };
            // Use "Environment.Exit(0);" if you want to implement an exit of the console program
            PokemonMenu();
        }
        static void PokemonMenu() {
    // From now on myDictionary is available for any menu option 
    var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      
    while (true) { // <- loop until exit option (key 'Q') is pressed
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Pokemon Pocket App!");
    Console.WriteLine("(1). Add Pokemon to my pocket");
    Console.WriteLine("(2). List Pokemon(s) in my pocket");
    Console.WriteLine("(3). Check if I can evolve Pokemon");
    Console.WriteLine("(4). Evolve Pokemon\n");
    Console.Write("Please only enter [1,2,3,4] or Q to exit:");

    char menu = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    if (menu == '1') { //Part 1
      Console.Write("Enter Pokemon Name :");
      string name = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.Write("Enter Pokemon HP : ");
      int hp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

      Console.Write("Enter Pokemon EXP : ");
      int exp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      if (myDictionary.Count <= 0) { 
        myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's Name", name);
        myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's HP", hp.ToString());
        myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's EXP", exp.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Pokemon has been added!");

      }
    }
    else if (menu == '2') { //Part 2
      foreach (var v in myDictionary)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{1}: {0}", v.Value, v.Key));
    }

    else if(menu == '3') { //Part  3

    }
    else if (menu == 'Q') {
      Console.WriteLine("App exited!");
      Environment.Exit(0);
        }
      }
     }
    }
}
```

After I have input the name, hp and exp, where name = "Charmander", "80" and "50" for example, it will be saved to the dictionary. When I enter 3 in the menu stage, I want the code to check if the Pokemon can evolve and write this:

```
Charmander --> Charmeleon
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Your "NoToEvolve" member is an integer: `public int NoToEvolve {get; set;}` What does that number mean? How does this number tell you if a Pokemon can evolve or not? What are valid values for this field? I'm sure the answer is a simple `if` statement, but you haven't given enough information for us to answer the question.

Comment: Maybe "if" can do I need try, but "NoToEvolve" is the evolution in the specific order, like if all 3 pokemon is in the dictionary, the pokemon with No 1 will evolve first and so on

Comment: Okay...again, there's not enough information here.  If "NoToEvolve" is simply an ordering field, what is used to determine if a Pokemon can evolve?  Is it the "exp" field?  If so, what are comparing that against?  Does each Pokemon have a different amount of XP that it needs?  Explain this in plain English, and show the relevant fields in your post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    
    namespace PokemonPocket
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //PokemonMaster list for checking pokemon evolution availability.    
                List<PokemonMaster> pokemonMasters = new List<PokemonMaster>(){
                new PokemonMaster("Pikachu", 2, "Raichu"),
                new PokemonMaster("Eevee", 3, "Flareon"),
                new PokemonMaster("Charmander", 1, "Charmeleon")
                };
                // Use "Environment.Exit(0);" if you want to implement an exit of the console program
                PokemonMenu(pokemonMasters);
            }
            static void PokemonMenu(List<PokemonMaster> pokemans)
            {
                // From now on myDictionary is available for any menu option 
                var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    
                while (true)
                { // <- loop until exit option (key 'Q') is pressed
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Pokemon Pocket App!");
                    Console.WriteLine("(1). Add Pokemon to my pocket");
                    Console.WriteLine("(2). List Pokemon(s) in my pocket");
                    Console.WriteLine("(3). Check if I can evolve Pokemon");
                    Console.WriteLine("(4). Evolve Pokemon\n");
                    Console.Write("Please only enter [1,2,3,4] or Q to exit:");
    
                    char menu = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    
                    if (menu == '1')
                    { //Part 1
                        Console.Write("Enter Pokemon Name :");
                        string name = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Enter Pokemon HP : ");
                        int hp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    
                        Console.Write("Enter Pokemon EXP : ");
                        int exp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (myDictionary.Count <= 0)
                        {
                            myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's Name", name);
                            myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's HP", hp.ToString());
                            myDictionary.Add("Pokemon's EXP", exp.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine("Pokemon has been added!");
    
                        }
                    }
                    else if (menu == '2')
                    { //Part 2
                        foreach (var v in myDictionary)
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{1}: {0}", v.Value, v.Key));
                    }
    
                    else if (menu == '3') //Part  3 // HERE IT IS!
                    {
                        if (!myDictionary.TryGetValue("Pokemon's Name", out var myPokemon))
                        {
                            // No pokemon in pocket so just exit
    
                            Console.WriteLine("You have no pokemon!");
                            continue;
                        }
    
                        var matchedPokemon = pokemans.Find(p => p.Name == myPokemon);
    
                        if (matchedPokemon != default)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Can evolve a pokeman!");
                            Console.WriteLine($"{matchedPokemon.Name} --> {matchedPokemon.EvolveTo}");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (menu == 'Q')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("App exited!");
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've passed in the `pokemonMasters` variable to `PokemonMenu` so the menu can see the available evolutions

Then in menu part 3 I can try and get the pokemon name from your dictionary, if there is one I can try and find that same name in the `pokemans` list I passed in. If I find a match there too I can write the evolution.

It's not pretty, but it works. Your method of using a dictionary to represent your pokemans is not going to work if you want to have more than one. You should probably instead use a list of objects.

Comment: This one works thanks, but could you explain what you did for `Console.WriteLine($"{matchedPokemon.Name} --> {matchedPokemon.EvolveTo}");`

Comment: @user15982865 that statement is equivalent to `Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} --> {1}", matchedPokemon.Name, matchedPokemon.EvolveTo)` but it uses newer syntax to make it a bit easier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated